# vis.js 3D bar graph: Set bar color based on z-coordinate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, graph, vis.js

I am trying to use Graph3d from vis.js to create a `bar-color` where I can control the bar color based on the z-coordinate value.

I have written a sample referring the examples and here the bar color depends on the z-coordinate or height of the bar. viz.js assigns the bar colors relatively, red for low values to blue for high values.

But the problem is if all data points have similar values, the bar color will be close to blue even if the actual values are very low. I would like the low values to be always red and high levels always green/blue. Is there a way of achieving that in viz.js?

```js
  var data = null;
    var graph = null;

 /**
  * Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
  */
 function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }
 
    // Called when the Visualization API is loaded.
    function drawVisualization() {
      var style = 'bar-color';
      // Create and populate a data table.
      data = new vis.DataSet();
   
   //Poppulating the data
      for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        for (var y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {
   var z = getRandomArbitrary(1,5);
   data.add({x:x, y:y, z:z, style:5-z});
        }
      }

      // specify options
      var options = {
        width:  '700px',
        height: '700px',
        style: style,
        showPerspective: true,
        showGrid: true,
        showShadow: false,
    verticalRatio: 0.5,
    zMin: 0,
    zMax: 5,
    xStep: 1,
    xCenter: '50%',
        yCenter: '30%',

        // Option tooltip can be true, false, or a function returning a string with HTML contents
        //tooltip: true,
        tooltip: function (point) {
          // parameter point contains properties x, y, z
          return 'value: <b>' + point.z + '</b>';
        },

        keepAspectRatio: true,
        verticalRatio: 0.5
      };

      var camera = graph ? graph.getCameraPosition() : null;

      // create our graph
      var container = document.getElementById('mygraph');
      graph = new vis.Graph3d(container, data, options);

      if (camera) graph.setCameraPosition(camera); // restore camera position
   
   var pos = {horizontal: 1.0, vertical: 0.5, distance: 2};
      graph.setCameraPosition(pos);
    }

drawVisualization();
```

```css
html, body {font: 10pt arial;
   padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   }
 
 #mygraph {
   padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/3.6.4/vis.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div id="mygraph"></div>
</body>
```

Here's the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NithishB/xrakvgrw/1/).

I am beginner in vis.js and couldn't find a way of achieving this even after spending hours on their documentation. If there is any other open source graphing solution which can do this rendering a similar looking graph, I would love to know that.

Comment: Hi nnb, I want to change my own color to be filled in graph3d bar chart. Can you please tell me how to overwrite `graph3d._hsv2rgb(h, s, v)` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color depends on the scale of the z-axis. If you manually set the axis range from 0-100 while all your data has values in the range 90-100, all data points will be red, and the graph looks almost flat. If you let the scale be determined automatically, it will just fit the data and scale the colors from min value (90) to max value (100).

There is no official feature to provide your own color scale function, but what you could do is replace the (internally used) graph3d._hsv2rgb(h, s, v) method with your own color scale function.

Comment: I am aware of that Jos. My data points will have the values between 0-5. My use case is to plot data from the last hour and I would like the scale to be set so that anyone seeing the graph can get the information at the first glance. i.e., If lot of data points have low height, they know that something is wrong and action needs to be taken. I would love to have the color enhance the presentation.

Comment: So you want some sort of non-linear color scale? It's a bit of a workaround, but what you could try to do is replace the (internally used) `graph3d._hsv2rgb(h, s, v)` method with your own color scale method.

Comment: Thanks Jos. I will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Hey Jos, thanks a lot for the tip. I made the change and now it works like a charm. :) Could you submit the info in your comment as another answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Could you please edit your answer or give a new answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Could you please look into my other post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459664/vis-js-graph3d-bar-graph-possible-bug

Comment: Wow!... I just noticed that you are a member of the Almende team which developed vis.js. :)

Comment: @JosdeJong : Hi Jos, Could you provide some fiddle example for overriding `graph3d._hsv2rgb(h, s, v)` for color based z co-ordinate values?